# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://user@172.28.0.51:9000/user/user/dict

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs, bigdata, hadoop-yarn

I would like to note that I'm a beginner working with the tools mentioned bellow, and dealing with a big data architecture is a first for me, so I apologize if I fail to communicate prpperly my problem or if anything is missing in my explanation. With that I appreciate any advice you can give me on how to solve this issue or even on how to increase my knowledge in this subject.
So I'm following this documentation: [https://halvadeforspark.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html][1]
[https://bitbucket.org/dries_decap/halvadeforspark/src/master/][1], Halvade on a local cluster.

I'm trying to apply this on a multi-node cluster, and the final step is to submit a spark application:

```
spark-submit --class be.ugent.intec.halvade.job.SomaticPipeline --master yarn    --deploy-mode client --driver-memory 4G --executor-memory 5G --total-executor-cores 8 --executor-cores 4 --num-executors 2 --conf "spark.executor.memoryOverhead=2048"   --conf "spark.task.cpus=1" --jars "../hadoop-bam-7.10.0.jar,../htsjdk-3.0.5.jar"  ../halvadeforspark/target/scala-2.12/halvade-assembly-2.0.6.jar --exome --normal "/input/normal/Exome_Norm/" --tumor "/input/tumor/Exome_Tumor/"  --output "output" --reference "ref/" --bindir "bin/" --variant_caller "strelka2"
```

but I'm getting this error, there are similar questions here but there was no solution to my issue. Exception:

```
3/06/24 09:59:31 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 33.2 KiB, free 2.2 GiB)
23/06/24 09:59:31 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 172.28.0.51:36141 (size: 33.2 KiB, free: 2.2 GiB)
23/06/24 09:59:31 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from textFile at FileUtils.scala:42
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://user@172.28.0.51:9000/user/user/dict
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:304)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:244)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:332)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:208)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:292)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:292)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:292)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedWithIndexRDD.<init>(ZippedWithIndexRDD.scala:44)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$zipWithIndex$1(RDD.scala:1410)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:406)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.zipWithIndex(RDD.scala:1410)
        at be.ugent.intec.halvade.FileUtils$.readDict(FileUtils.scala:42)
        at be.ugent.intec.halvade.job.SomaticPipeline$.runPipeline(SomaticPipeline.scala:140)
        at be.ugent.intec.halvade.job.HalvadeJob.main(HalvadeJob.scala:149)
        at be.ugent.intec.halvade.job.SomaticPipeline.main(SomaticPipeline.scala)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:958)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1046)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1055)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://user@172.28.0.51:9000/user/user/dict
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:278)
        ... 36 more
```

so I'm using an already existing code /jar files (as I mentioned above). According to this:

```
3/06/24 09:59:31 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from textFile at FileUtils.scala:42
```

This is the code responsible for the directory input, it's derived from [https://bitbucket.org/dries_decap/halvadeforspark/src/master/src/main/scala/be/ugent/intec/halvade/FileUtils.scala][1]:

```scala
package be.ugent.intec.halvade

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
import java.io.{File, PrintWriter}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

object FileUtils extends be.ugent.intec.halvade.Logging {
  def deleteRecursively(f: File): Boolean = {
    if(!f.exists()) return true // for if the folder doesn't exist!
    if (f.isDirectory) f.listFiles match {
      case null =>
      case xs   => xs foreach deleteRecursively
    }
    f.delete()
  }

  def deleteRecursively(path: String): Boolean = {
    val f: File = new File(path)
    deleteRecursively(f)
  }

  def printToFile(f: File)(op: PrintWriter => Unit) {
    val p = new PrintWriter(f)
    try { op(p) }
    finally { p.close() }
  }
  def printArrayToFile[T](array: Array[T], outputfile: String) = {
    printToFile(new File(outputfile)) {
      p => array.foreach(p.println)
    }
  }

  def readBqsrTable(path: String): String = {
    if (path != null) scala.io.Source.fromFile(path).mkString
    else null
  }
  def readDict(sc: SparkContext, path: String): Map[String, DictIndexAndPosition] = {
    // path should be on file://
    var path_with_fs = path
    if(path.startsWith("/")) path_with_fs = "file://" + path
    sc.textFile(path_with_fs).filter(x => x.startsWith("@SQ")).zipWithIndex.map(x => {
                       var chr = ""
                       var len = 0
                       x._1.split("\t").foreach(y => {
                         val tmp = y.indexOf(":");
                         if (tmp > 0 && y.substring(0, tmp) == "SN") chr = y.substring(tmp + 1)
                         if (tmp > 0 && y.substring(0, tmp) == "LN") len = y.substring(tmp + 1).toInt
                       })
                       (chr, DictIndexAndPosition(x._2.toInt, len))
                     }).collect.toMap
  }

}
```

I tried changing the directory so many times, even with putting the path to hdfs files instead of the local files I get the same error. So any insight on how I can troubleshoot this or on what I'm missing or not understanding would be much appreciated.
Note: to my understanding the issue is not in the code, it's in my configuration.
Thank you.